# How to migrate/makemigrations in one app with multiple databases

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm working on a django project with:

- One single app
- Three huge identical mysql databases with historical data
- One mysql database where I store results from calculations of the historical data

I'm struggling with how to makemigrations/migrate when I make changes to the models.

With only one database I would simple do something like:

```
$ manage.py makemigrations <app_name>
$ manage.py migrate <app_name> 0001
```

But this creates tables for every model in every database. I've tried to mess around with:

```
$ manage.py migrate <app_name> 0001 --database==<name_of_db>
```

But is this all I should do? I have looked into routers but I don't really understand how to configure one for this case.

**In short: My goal is to be able to update a model and then only migrate the changes to the relevant databases.** In some cases the updated model should migrate to the three identical databases, in other cases the updated model should only migrate to the one unique database.

All help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

i found this django docs. i think its helpful
[image: Django documentation about database routers]